# Unable to Run bacon Function with control Variables: Fixed-Effects Error

Tags: r, regression

I'm facing an issue while using the bacon function for analysis. My dataset consists of a dependent variable Treatment and independent variables post
, and one control variable, where both post and the control variable are binary variables (0 and 1).

When I run the following code, it works without any errors:

```
p1_bacon <- bacon(Treatment ~ post, 
                  data = test,
                  id_var = "city",
                  time_var = "Date",
                  quietly = FALSE)
```

However, when I include both post and the control variables in the model like this:

```
p1_bacon <- bacon(Treatment ~ post + control variable, 
                  data = test,
                  id_var = "city",
                  time_var = "Date",
                  quietly = FALSE)
```

I encounter the following error: Error in fixest::feols(treated ~ 1 | time + id, data = data):
The dependent variable is a constant. The estimation with fixed-effects cannot be done.
I'd appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

I have changed different control variables, it still said error when adding other control variables.
Also, I have excluded the samples randomly, but it still said error.

I expect to get a normal Bacon result. Thank you very much!